# QuickOSM error when installing

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, quickosm

I tried installing the QuickOSM plugin but when the installations finishes, i get the following error:

```
Couldn't load plugin 'QuickOSM' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 

FileExistsError: [WinError 183] A file cannot be created, when it already exists:
'C:\\Users\\ri\\AppData\\Roaming\\QGIS\\QGIS3\\profiles\\default\\python\\plugins\\QuickOSM\\resources\\i18n\\preset_cs-rCZ.po' -> 
'C:\\Users\\ri\\AppData\\Roaming\\QGIS\\QGIS3\\profiles\\default\\python\\plugins\\QuickOSM\\resources\\i18n\\preset_cs_CZ.po' 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 423, in _startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:\Users/ri/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\__init__.py", line 12, in classFactory
    return QuickOSMPlugin(iface)
  File "C:\Users/ri/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\quick_osm.py", line 74, in __init__
    self.extract_zip_file()
  File "C:\Users/ri/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\quick_osm.py", line 123, in extract_zip_file
    os.rename(file_path, new_file_path)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] A file cannot be created, when it already exists: 'C:\\Users\\ri\\AppData\\Roaming\\QGIS\\QGIS3\\profiles\\default\\python\\plugins\\QuickOSM\\resources\\i18n\\preset_cs-rCZ.po' -> 'C:\\Users\\ri\\AppData\\Roaming\\QGIS\\QGIS3\\profiles\\default\\python\\plugins\\QuickOSM\\resources\\i18n\\preset_cs_CZ.po'
```

I'm new to python programming and QGIS so the only thing I tried so far was deleting the files "preset_cs_CZ.po" and "preset_cs-rCZ.po" and reinstalling the plugin and it didn't work. Also, I tried reinstalling QGIS with the plugin as well and it also didn't help at all.

Comment: I think it's a QuickOSM bug. I will fix it ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

This is now fixed in version 2.1.1.